# Is there a way to enable Firebase Auth via Email through an API/CLI?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, terraform

We are transitioning to using Terraform to create our architecture on Google Compute, and part of it utilises Firebase for the front-end. So far, I have managed to get this all working fine, but have hit a snag on Firebase Auth. Essentially, I want to allow 'Email/Password' authentication on a Firbase project programmatically.

[image: How it looks in the console]

The above shows where you find the setting in the UI console, but I want to be able to do that via an API/CLI, and also set the 'Authorised Domain'.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, this is something you'd want to bring up with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as of [November 2022](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/8288#event-7763890540), this is now possible, either using [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io), or the [gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud) and a bit of scripting. Both methods make use of the [REST Identity Toolkit API](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest).

**If using Terraform:** Your config file needs to specify a [`google_identity_platform_project_default_config`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/identity_platform_project_default_config) resource: the documentation for it is available [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/identity_platform_project_default_config). By way of example – assuming you've already declared a `google_project` resource called `my_project`, you could add the `google_identity_platform_project_default_config` resource as follows:

```
resource "google_identity_platform_project_default_config" "myconfig" {

    project = google_project.myproject.project_id 

    sign_in {
        allow_duplicate_emails = false

        anonymous {
            enabled = false
        }

        email {
            enabled = true
            password_required = false
        }
    }
}
```

This would enable email+password authentication, disallow anonymous access, and disallow duplicate email addresses.

**If using the gcloud CLI:** This would be a good deal fiddlier. I haven't tested it out completely, but it is presumably equivalent to what Terraform is doing behind the scenes. You need to obtain a service account access token, then use cURL (or a similar tool/API) to amend the Identity Toolkit configuration using the PATCH method (documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/updateConfig)), supplying the token in the "Authorization" header.

`gcloud` lets you get an access token using the command `gcloud auth print-access-token`, but according to [this 2021 blog post](https://pretired.dazwilkin.com/posts/211026/)<sup>1</sup> by [@DazWilkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/609290/dazwilkin), the token obtained using your regular human credentials can't perform the necessary PATCH operation; you need to use a token backed by a service account that has the correct permissions.

The [blog post](https://pretired.dazwilkin.com/posts/211026/) gives further details, but roughly, the steps are:

1. Create a service account and give it the correct permissions. (Not necessary if you already have an appropriate service account; such an account can be created either using the Firebase console or Terraform's `google_service_account` resource.)
2. Create a [JSON service account key file](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys). (Not necessary if you already have a key created, plus a JSON file for it. These JSON files contain an object with the keys "project_id", "private_key_id", and "private_key", and are exactly the same sort of file as gets generated from the Firebase console if you go to "Project Overview" / "Project Settings" / "Service Accounts" / "Generate new private key". They can also be created programmatically using Terraform's `google_service_account_key` resource.)
3. Allow `gcloud` to perform operations using the service account's permissions, by running `gcloud`'s "`auth activate-service-account`" subcommand: something like

   ```
    $ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/path/to/key-file.json EMAIL_ADDRESS_OF_SERVICE_ACCOUNT
   ```
4. Obtain an access token for the service account by running `gcloud auth print-access-token EMAIL_ADDRESS_OF_SERVICE_ACCOUNT`.
5. Supply that token in the header of an HTTP PATCH request using cURL.

For more details, see the blog post; it's concerned with amending the "authorized domains" list for a Firebase project, but enabling email/password authentication would be very similar.

---

<sup>1</sup> Also mentioned in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70342489/6818792).