# How to configure google identity platform with CLI sdk?

Tags: gcloud, google-identity

I am trying to change google identity platform configuration with cli using gcloud CLI SDK for linux.

to be specific I want to call these API [getConfig](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/getConfig) and [UpdateConfig](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/updateConfig)

Is there a way to do this using gcloud cli? there seems to be a group called `Identity` as per the docs, but this does not seem to be doing what I want

Comment: I was challenged to understand Identity Toolkit. There already to be multiple variants and I didn't understand the nuances. I wanted to be able to programmatically control Firebase Auth authorized domains (part of the config). Ultimately, I resorted to using `curl` and the REST API. I blogged about my experience: https://pretired.dazwilkin.com/posts/211026/

Comment: @DazWilkin, it does work! Try posting your answer as a formal answer to help other users that have a similar problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I struggled using Google's Identity Toolkit/Platform and how these correspond with Firebase-Auth too.

The term is overloaded by Google and Cloud Identity, Identity Platform and Firebase Auth have overlapping sets of functionality.

| Name | URL |
| --- | --- |
| Cloud Identity API | cloudidentity.googleapis.com |
| Identity Toolkit API | identitytoolkit.googleapis.com |

> **NOTE** Identity Toolkit is **inaccessible** through Google [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer)

I wanted to be able to programmatically update Firebase Auth's authorized domains.

By observing the calls made by Firebase Console, I needed to use [`getConfig`](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/getConfig) and [`updateConfig`](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/updateConfig) too.

These **aren't** surfaced through `gcloud`.

Essentially:

1. `GET` the response from `getConfig`
2. I used [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to transform it into my desired state
3. `PATCH` `config`<sup>1</sup> using an `updateMask`

<sup>1</sup> The endpoint for the `updateConfig` method is actually (just) `config`

This worked for me and hopefully helps you better understand how you can use these methods directly.

I blogged about it more comprehensively [here](https://pretired.dazwilkin.com/posts/211026/)