# How can I manage domains for identity platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I've configured identity platform for my project. Now I have pull request environments spinning up automatically with render.com. So for auth to work, I need to add each domain to the security settings of my identity platform configuration.

I didn't find a way how this can be achieved via CLI or terraform or REST APIs. I would be looking for pointers to documentation/tools on how I can update this information programatically.

Thanks

Christian

Comment: For identity platform, you have a list of domains that can be the target of the redirect after authentication. They are managed at https://console.cloud.google.com/customer-identity/settings. There, you don't need domain verification.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the REST API to read and update the config. Documentation [for the config](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/Config) and [to update it](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/updateConfig)

**Note** you need to create a service account, your personal credentials are rejected by the API.

Sample code in java script:

```js
import { GoogleAuth } from 'google-auth-library';
import { request } from 'undici';

const serviceAccount = "email of the service account"

const auth = new GoogleAuth({
  clientOptions: { targetPrincipal: serviceAccount },
});
const client = await auth.getClient();
const tokenResponse = await client.getAccessToken();

const domains = [ 'example.com', 'www.example.com' ]

const configUpdateResponse = await request(
  `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/admin/v2/projects/your-project-goes-here/config?updateMask=authorizedDomains`,
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + tokenResponse.token,
      'X-Goog-User-Project': 'your-project-goes-here',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    method: 'PATCH',
    body: JSON.stringify({ authorizedDomains: domains }),
  }
);


const configResponse = await request(
  `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/admin/v2/projects/your-project-goes-here/config`,
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + tokenResponse.token,
      'X-Goog-User-Project': 'your-project-goes-here',
    },
    method: 'GET',
  }
);

const config = await configResponse.body.json();
console.log('Authorized domains are now: ', config.authorizedDomains);
```

Comment: The list of domains can also be amended programmatically using gcloud + cURL - see @DazWilkin's answer to a different question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70342489/6818792 - which is expanded on in his blog: https://pretired.dazwilkin.com/posts/211026/. However, it seems it can't (as at January 2023) currently be amended using Terraform.